# Installing a different edition of Windows 8 on an OEM system

Tags: windows-8, product-key, windows-edition

My PC comes with an OEM copy of Windows 8 (regular), but I only have a Windows 8 Professional DVD. Will Windows 8 automatically detect the edition associated with the product key in my BIOS and install Windows 8 (regular) instead of allowing me to enter the key for the Professional edition?

(I have an Asus Q200E Win 8 Core OEM laptop. I borrowed a Windows 8 Professional DVD from my friends, so naturally, I can’t use his product key.)

Comment: It should work but there is no guarantee you really should use the ISO meant for Windows 8 Core.

Comment: @Ramhound my pc didn't come with one =(

Comment: If your pc came with windows 8 then it has a recovery partition unless you deleted it.  If you did then contact the brand and request one.  Its unlikely your OEM key will be automatically picked up by a Windows 8 Pro media depending on what its actually use ( curious of the source ).

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean curious of the source?

Comment: No one can answer this question without knowing the make and model of the PC. Most PC's have the ability to make factory recovery discs.

Comment: @user22105 - How do you have a Windows 8 Professional CD if you don't have a Windows 8 Core CD?  If you have a Windows 8 Professional CD you should have a Windows 8 Professional License.

Comment: @Ramhound i borrowed the Pro cd from a friend, of course i can't use his key...

Comment: @Moab laptop is made by Asus, model Q200E

Comment: @user22105 - Both of your last comments is important information so update your question.  HackToHell's answer is the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the contents of the DVD onto a folder and then go to `/sources` and create a file called ei.cfg, and paste the following info in it.

> [EditionID]
>
> [Channel]
>   OEM

Now make an ISO of the folder and burn it onto a DVD, now during installation, you will get a popup asking you to select the version, select Windows 8 Core and it must work