# How do I find my product key for Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, product-key

My computer was pre-installed by Dell with Windows 8. I upgraded to 8.1. I have a USB drive from Dell with Windows 8. I clicked "Add Features to Windows 8.1" in control panel, but it asks for my product key. How do I find out my current product key?

I tried this answer https://superuser.com/a/952806/130929

And got a key

[image]

But it didn't work in Control Panel

[image]

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to retrieve your Windows 8.1 license key.  The Windows 8.1 installation environment will automatically detect your key.  Windows 8 license keys can activate Windows 8.1 but Windows 8.1 license keys can not activate Windows 8 installations.  I am not shocked the program you tried didn’t detect the correct key.

Comment: Well please explain why the control panel applet is asking for my product key!

Comment: The Windows 8.1 installation environment doesn’t accept Windows 8 keys but you can activate Windows 8.1 with a Windows 8 license.

Comment: I already have Windows 8.1 activated. This is only in the control panel applet.

Comment: You are either trying to use a license key to a different version of Windows than you have installed.  The only feature you can add is the Media Center.  Are you sure you are not trying to add the Media Center?  Is your installation activated?

Comment: Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/650019/how-to-use-windows-8-1-rtm-with-8-0-key/650055#650055

Comment: product id shows you got the OEM key. if this key is for Core/Home, you need to purchase a win Pro key