# Installed Windows 10 in a VirtualBox VM, is it possible to find the OEM product key?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an HP Z230 workstation which came with Windows 8.1 Pro downgraded to Windows 7 Pro preinstalled.

I have since replaced the harddrive and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it.

I have also installed VirtualBox, and installed Windows 10 Pro in a VM.

From looking online I understand the product key is in the UEFI firmware?

The activation screen in Windows 10 says:

> We can't activate Windows on this device because the previous version of Windows was not activated prior to upgrading to Windows 10. Go to the Store to buy genuine Windows. Error code: 0x803F7001

**Questions:**

- Am I able to use the Windows 8.1 product key from my bios to activate Windows 10 in my vm?
- If so, how can I retrieve the product key (using Ubuntu 16.04)?

Comment: You are not going to be able to activate an OEM copy of Windows 8.1 running on a VM, even if that VM, is running on the OEM equipment

Comment: I know of only two programs that display the license key stored in the ACPI table.  Both are Windows programs.  The first is [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus).  The other is, [RW Everything](http://rweverything.com/), which shows you the raw data.

Comment: [How to extract Win 8 OEM key embedded in the BIOS?](http://superuser.com/questions/513904/how-to-extract-win-8-oem-key-embedded-in-the-bios/593795#593795)

Comment: I should point out.  Unless you upgrade your Windows 8.1 installation to Windows 10 BEFORE July 29 2016, you can't use your Windows 8.1 key, to install Windows 10.  If you want to use Windows 10, now that the free offer has expired, your only option is to purchase a Windows 10 retail key.

Comment: @Ramhound the linked duplicate worked for me. `sudo cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM` yields the product key. I was able to successfully enter that key and activate my copy of Windows 10.