# hp elitbook 840 G2 touchsreen core I7

Tags: windows

I would like to figure out what version of Windows came with my laptop windows 7 /8/10  which  was originally so I can install that and use the product key..  as this laptop I taken from some who doesn’t know ..now its running windows 10 pro due to some issue I want to setup new windows

Comment: Unless this is a pirated copy of Windows 10 then chances are it has a digital entitlement. Simply reinstall Windows 10, skip entering a product key, connect to the internet and it should reactivate itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't have a product key sticker at the bottom, then it came with Windows 8, 8.1 or 10 and the product key is embedded in the motherboard memory.

Windows 10 will accept Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 keys too, so you can safely install it. If laptop has the embedded key, you can choose "I don't have product key" in the installer, it will read it from motherboard memory.

Comment: my laptop main probel is now windows update area at the top notification pop up that some setting are manage by your organization.. and also now showing activation windows  status  your windows is activated by your organization  that's why i want to setup new windows ..

Comment: Sure, you can do that. Installing Windows 10 will be the easiest way to go.

Comment: If I setup new windows are going to activate automatically or I have to buy ...

Comment: As I wrote in the answer: if the laptop has an embedded license key, it will be read by the installer. If it doesn't, it should have a license sticker at the bottom. You can check if the embedded key is there using [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/593795/194694).

Comment: Now I activated my windows successfully with digital keys but only problem is windows update area still showing some settings are managed by your organization

Comment: That's a separate problem, please ask a new question.