# Reinstalling a fresh Windows 8 on my new laptop

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation, oem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing a different edition of Windows 8 on an OEM system](https://superuser.com/questions/512123/installing-a-different-edition-of-windows-8-on-an-oem-system)

OK I have a new Dell (Inspiron 15R 5520) laptop that came with Windows 8 pre-installed.

I'm really not a fan of pre-installed Windows since they are bundled with tons of softwares I don't want and settings I don't like.

I would like to reinstall it myself with a fresh installation. I have bought Windows 8 Pro OEM already for my desktop computer and it came with the usual OEM sticker with the Windows serial on it. Now my new laptop only have a Windows 8 logo sticker on it with no serial on it. After some research it seems [it's normal](http://technewspedia.com/the-serial-number-for-windows-8-will-come-built-into-the-bios/).

Now, can I format my laptop and install Windows 8 (**not** pro) from my Windows 8 **Pro** OEM DVD?

I ask because when I installed Windows 8 Pro it asked for the serial (which was found on the sticker). I'm wondering if the same DVD will detect the serial on the BIOS of my new laptop or I need a special Dell DVD for that?

Comment: Windows 8 computers do not come with a COA sticker.  So how exactly did you get a Windows 8 computer with a Windows 8 COA sticker on it?  You need to use a Windows 8 Professional installation disk, the installer will automatically detect the authentication code stored in the bios, there are many articles on this subject.

Comment: @Ramhound I bought my Windows 8 Pro alone (DVD only). So I had a COA sticker with it since it's not bundled with new hardware.

Comment: @AkexV - This is important information you should update your question to reflect this.  The reason I was confused is because its not called `Windows 8 Professional OEM` its called `Windows 8 Professional System Builder` its slightly confusing because the same product can be used for personal use and OEM use but has different license terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, even though technically the DVD contains both versions.

However you can look at [this hack](http://www.howtogeek.com/126093/how-to-get-all-the-windows-8-editions-on-one-install-disk/) i wrote about, on How-To Geek, that will allow you to install the normal Windows 8 version by modding the ISO, which will detect your key.