# Can I install Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, license, license-key

I bought a laptop that came with Windows 8 installed. There were problems with my laptop and I couldn’t even use the Windows 8 refresh or restart, so I installed Ubuntu. I now have only Ubuntu on my laptop and was wondering if there was any way I could go back to Windows 8 without paying. In my BIOS, it says my factory installed OS is Windows 8, and I have the sticker on my laptop to prove it in case I have to send it in.

**EDIT 1:**

I called them and they said it would cost $30 to get another cd.

My sticker looks like the one on the left.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

- My laptop is an HP Pavilion g6
- I have wiped the partition and there is only one with Ubuntu on it.
- I *think* I have my win 8 serial written somewhere
- Nowhere on the PC does it have any key.
- I have a legal Win XP SP2 cd (with key) if that helps.

Comment: Dont you have a code on that sticker?

Comment: No, it's just a sticker with the windows 8 logo on the back. Though I used a program to find my code and have it written somewhere (I think).

Comment: If you blew away your recovery partition, and didn't make recovery disks, then contact your notebook manufacturer for install disks.  You may have to pay, but it's less than a new license/copy of Windows 8.

Comment: I'll call them up, and does this mean that my serial is useless?

Comment: `it's just a sticker with the windows 8 logo on the back.` Wait, what kind of laptop is it? Are you saying it’s [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HHdcR.jpg)?

Comment: Yes the sticker is like that.

Comment: Did you look at the other stickers? Are you sure there is no key printed *anywhere*? If not, then you need to ask your laptop manufacturer about what to do. Aside from the recovery disc ($30‽), there may also be a recovery partition or something. We have no way of knowing because you did not even say what kind of laptop it is.

Comment: I've added some more information.

Comment: @user2612619 - The answer to the current revision is that the $30 is required to get a recovery cd from the oem.  Technically you can create your own `Windows 8` disk ( note Windows 8 Professional will not work ) if you decide that route do your research to verify the disk has not be altered.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there was any way I could go back to Windows 8 without paying.

Yes, you just need your Windows serial number.

> In my BIOS it says my factory installed OS is Windows 8 and I have the sticker on my laptop to prove it in case I have to send it in. There's just a sticker with the windows 8 logo on the back.

The sticker should have a code imprinted on it.

> Though I used a program to find my code and have it written somewhere (I think)

That will work too (though your sticker *should* have the code).

> I'll call them up, and does this mean that my serial is useless?

No, you only need the code. You will have the opportunity to type in your code either during the install or after booting up. You will then have to activate Windows as normal (either over the Internet or over the phone).

Here’s a Windows 8 COA sticker I found through Google Images. This one has not been affixed to a system yet and part of the key is redacted:

[image: Photo of Windows 8 COA sticker]

Here’s another one without the surrounding cardboard and with the key blurred out:

[image: Photo of another Windows 8 COA sticker]

Comment: How would I install it? I don't have a cd or the restore partition.

Comment: Then you should update your question because it currently only asks about the legality of re-installing. As others have said, check the recovery-partition that came with the laptop. If you deleted that while installing Ubuntu, then you need to check that question that was linked which asks about the legality of downloading a Windows install disc.

Comment: I don't have a spare CD and would like to solve this without one unless I have to go out and buy one.

Comment: Not all Windows 8 computers have the serial sticker anymore.  See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/514667/reinstalling-a-fresh-windows-8-on-my-new-laptop) and [here](http://technewspedia.com/the-serial-number-for-windows-8-will-come-built-into-the-bios/). So the serialnumber should be stored in bios in this case and the Windows install (if chosen the right cd) should activate itself with that number in the bios. Maybe a generic iso image from Microsoft will work.

Comment: So I should download win 8 from the site, burn to a USB and it'll install for me without needing a key?

Comment: Yes. If your system doesn’t have the key displayed in a human-readable form, then it is in the OEM BIOS. That’s why you see Windows listed in there; because your laptop manufacturer uses a customized BIOS software which allows them to embed individual codes in it (as opposed universal to per-manufacturer keys like with Windows 7). In this case, you’ll need to download a Windows ISO and “burn” it to either a disc (a DVD+RW would work just fine), or a USB flash-drive. Then you can install and it should pick up the key automatically. But first, make *sure* you really do have *only one* partition.

Comment: `the serial number is on a sticker pasted on the bottom of the device, leaving visible when the model is on display. And although he spends little, there are times when the same PC that was on show then sold, and if some curious looked license number and stole it, can be a problem. To fix this, Microsoft has included a new feature in Windows 8, which stores the number in the internal memory of the bios on the motherboard, not visible from the outside of the notebook casing.` @Rik, that second link was great. `:-D` The real reason they changed it was because the per-mfg keys led to mass piracy.